Why do my photos go dark on the screen playback after 2 seconds on my Nikon Z50
I have just purchased the Nikon Z50 twin lens kit. I am getting to know it but when I use the playback (i) button to look at my photos, after a couple seconds, the photo goes dark and I am unable to see it properly. Its like the screen goes into power saver.  I have looked at different settings but as I am new to this, I feel like I am stumbling around. I have it set on NEF (RAW) +jpeg normal. I have tried taking photos in different settings ie P,M and auto but it makes no difference. I haven't had much time to use it yet, but each time I do, I have this problem and it stops me from taking more, as I want to see the result. I have looked on Nikon Z50 manual online but cant find any answer there. I would greatly appreciate anyone's suggestions. Thank you

How full is the battery?

What do you have set for the "Power Off Delay" on "Playback"? (Custom Settings menu item c3, full reference manual (not the shorter User Guide), page 277 [English version (En)10].)

Thank you, thank you, thank you❤️. After hours of searching, you solved it for me! I am so very grateful for your help. Now I can get out there and immerse myself in taking heaps of photos.
